# Using a loop to find the smallest non zero value in a set of columns

Tags: r, loops

Suppose I have a data set

```
 set2_data
```

and in that data set there are 33 columns.  My main objective is to find the lowest non zero value in every column besides the first one. so I was trying the following methods:

```
dade2 <- names(set2_data)[2:33]
for (i in 2:33) {
  print(min(set2_data[dade2[i]]))
}
```

The code above worked, but it includes 0.  So then I tried this:

```
dade2 <- names(set2_data)[2:33]
for (i in 2:33) {
  print(min(set2_data[dade2[i]][which(set2_data[dade2[i]]>0)]))
}
```

If I want to determine the values individually I can use this:

```
min(set2_data[,1][which(set2_data[,1]!=0)])
```

but this is horribly inefficient and I am wondering why does this work but the loop above not?

Thank you!

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible and include some data as well as expected output.

Comment: *lowest non zero value* is not `> 0`, but `!= 0` as you're excluding negative values now.

Comment: Do you have negative numbers or do you refer to the lowest positive value across all columns?

Comment: There are no negatives but I still want it to work if there are negative values.  I changed it. Thank you @PoGibas

Comment: see the prev. comment thank you for bringing that up @HarroCyranka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would try to do using sapply (usually faster than a for-loop)

```
library(tidyverse)

##Mock data
set.seed(3)
x <- bind_cols(lapply(1:33, function(i)rnorm(1000,mean = 1,sd = 2)))

##Apply the function to each column: 
##First, subset the non-zero elements, then find the smallest one
vector_of_mins <- sapply(x[,2:33], function(i)min(i[i!=0]))

##Similar example with only positive numbers
my_vector <- c(0,1,1.5,2,3,4,5) ##Smallest number should be zero

min(my_vector[my_vector!=0]) ##Retrieves the smallest non-zero (1)
```

Comment: You're amazing.  Thank you so much.  Exactly what I was looking for.